# om get-props vs get-state

Tags: clojurescript, om

I am trying to grasp the purpose of the two OM functions get-state and get-props. Have a look at the following example:

```
(defn example [app owner]
  (reify
    om/IInitState
    (render-state [this state]
      (println "app-state: " app )
      (println "state: " state )
      (println "get-props: " (om/get-props owner) )
      (println "get-state: " (om/get-state owner) )
      (dom/div nil "hello"))))
```

You will notice that `app` and `state` contain exactly what `get-props` and `get-state` return, which seems at the first glance pretty redundant.

Now, not all the lifecycle functions (e.g. `IWillMount` ) pass the `state` argument, so when you need it in such circumstances, it's obvious that you need to invoke `om/get-state` to get access to it.

However, for the app-state it looks different to me. You always have the app-state cursor available in all functions since it's a top-level argument of the function, even if you need it in callbacks you can just pass it around. Most examples/tutorials make use of `get-state` but I can't find an example of `get-props`. Is get-props redundant? Where would I use it?

And one more thing related to this construct. In React we have props and state, but in OM we have app-state and state (internal state) which confused me when learning OM. Props are passed from parent to child in React, likewise in OM we pass app-state (cursors) to children. Are the following observations valid?

- app-state is the OM equivalent of React' props
- props is React is just data, while app-state in OM is data wrapped in cursors
- this means that OM doesn't have props, only app-state cursors, hence the function `get-props` really means `get-app-state`

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the distinction between app-state and component state. get-props is about app-state (ie. props in React), while get-state is about component state. And figuring out what should be app-state and what should be component state is not necessarily simple.

Comment: I don't think I miss this distinction, as you see in the question I distinguish between app-state (props equivalent) and "internal state" (local component state) . What is not clear is the function get-props. Why is there when I have the cursor anyway? And since there are no props in OM, I find this name confusing. Can't find an example that shows how to utilize this fn. But you're right, figuring out what goes into app-state/local-state is very tricky.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I am going from regular React to Om and this app-state vs props distinction is super confusing. I too don't understand why get-props exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, `get-props` is mostly (or exclusively) needed in the `IWillReceiveProps` phase. `will-receive-props` gets a `next-props` argument, which contains the future app-state/props. `get-props` gives you the current app-state/props so that you can compare the two.

From [the Om docs](https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Documentation#iwillreceiveprops) for `IWillReceiveProps`:

> In your implementation if you wish to detect prop transitions you
>   must use `om.core/get-props` to get the previous props. This is 
>   because your component constructor function is called with the 
>   updated props.

So the rest of the time, `get-props` isn't necessary because, as mentioned in the question, you have access to the cursor.

Comment: it could still be useful in helper functions. For example, I often pass `owner` to helper functions so I can access local state, so using `get-props` could save on arguments since you can access app-state through `owner`. Certainly not necessary, but could be useful, I guess.

Comment: So `will-receive-props` passes the `next-props` to your function which is redundant since the component constructor also has the updated props. In that case `get-props` is the only way to get the old props. Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.